# Implementing OAuth for Desktop application

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

For a desktop application, how can I get the access token by participating directly in the OAuth flows.

I don't want the user to go through browser and provide me the access token.

Secondly, how can I know what are the users the application is authorized by 
and how the application can know if it is authorized by somebody and what is the access token for the same ?

Comment: Is this a Facebook Oauth question or a Google Oauth question?  What are you trying to do access the API or let them login to your application using Oauth2?

Comment: Currently I want to use Google oauth from which I would want them to login into my application using oauth2

Comment: You can't really use a user's token without have him authorize you do to so. This latter authorization process is exactly "going through browser".

Comment: Why do you need a web browser to do this? Can we do it by building a custom app that fetches the response and serves request in regards to the POST/GET.

Comment: That's up to the provider to decide what is the supported UI cause he's supposed to take care of security issues (spoofing, phishing, etc.). As a google user, how can I be sure you're not stealing my password if you present me with a custom UI? (in fact, I will never put my password in a custom so-called google UI, I want the standard one, in a browser)

Comment: Yup, I agree that presenting a custom UI we would need to program like any other web browser , implemeting the correct protocols,security procedures and as far as any website should know that it's a browser.

Answer (score 1):

**"how can I get the access token by participating directly in the OAuth flows."**

By storing a refresh token in your server

**Secondly, how can I know what are the users the application is authorized by**

The user can only authorize your app with your app's involvement. So you simply need to store a each authed user in a list

**and how the application can know if it is authorized by somebody and what is the access token for the same ?**

By attempting to do an auth with force-approval = false; If he is authed, you'll get an access token. If he isn't, he'll be prompted for auth.